# Using SBLIM CIM Client (for Java) with WS-Management protocol

Tags: java, web-services

I have been searching for a Java sample code using SBLIM CIM Client (version: 2.2.5) to talk to a WS-Management server, but couldn't find any.

I see that SBLIM client has a string constant (PROTOCOL_WSMANAGEMENT) defined to support WS-Management (along with PROTOCOL_CIMXML). But, when I use PROTOCOL_WSMANAGEMENT in my code, I get an IllegalArgumentException that says"WS-Management is not a supported protocol".

Specifically, I want my Java client code (using SBLIM) to talk to a WINRM service running on a remote Windows machine.

Can someone help me please?

-Venu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBLIM CIM Client for Java doesn't support WS-Management protocol as of 2.2.5.